# Is hierarchical tagging correct

Tags: discussion, tags

I see often people tag questions like
[wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) [wpf-controls](/questions/tagged/wpf-controls) [wpf-datagrid](/questions/tagged/wpf-datagrid) [wpf-datagrid-columns](/questions/tagged/wpf-datagrid-columns)

And then ask a question about columns.

Because tags are oriented towards the people that will answer the question, and google searching is sufficient, I see tags as categories, so I would retag as:

[wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) [grid](/questions/tagged/grid)

That way people with wpf experience, and people with grid experience can help. You'd likely get more help from wpf programmers, but maybe someone with some Winforms grid experience pickup something others don't notice.

In my opinion, you shouldn't assign multiple tags within the same topic with varying levels of specificity. The tags you assign should be one per topic with the exact specificity you need to answer your question.

Another example of this way of tagging:

[wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) [styles](/questions/tagged/styles)

I've started to suggest that people do this in comments, and have even edited questions in this manner.

**Before I continue!**

Am I correct?

See my [example edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15642847/revisions)

Comment: All of the hyphenated tags you've mentioned are *specific* to the technology being used.  They're fine.  In fact, they're great.  Tags that aren't ambiguous make the New Tag Deletionist Cabal very pleased.

Comment: @Charles It's not whether the tags are fine. If the wpf-datagrid tag has sufficient content to have people specialize in it then fine. However, [tag:C#-double] doesn't have sufficient information to specialize in it, so I can't see it being a tag. My question isn't whether the tags should exist, but whether you should assign them all. If you think the question really relates to [tag:wpf-datagrid-columns], then that's the only tag you should use.

Comment: Well I guess I'm going to stop here. Because I think I carry a different philosophy on tagging. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 5):

Tagging should follow a simple formula:

> Can you see someone following this tag on the site or through <strike>Google Reader</strike> their favorite RSS reader?

If the answer to that question is yes, it meets the most basic criteria for being a tag (there are other criteria).  If that question is no, then the tag probably shouldn't exist.  In this case, There are at least two tags that should not exist.

Comment: I'm ok with the tags existing. I'm wanting to know if it's incorrect to assign them all. Tags should draw different crowds, and you should assign the correct specificity for each category. If you think that people specializing in [tag:grid] can answer your question, include that tag. But don't overlap tags of varying specificity within the same topic area. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think you're correct, not for that tag anyway. The wpf tag is huge. Over 60,000 questions. Tagging something with [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) is handy, it will make it turn colour on the main screen for those who've marked it as an interesting tag, but it's just not enough. Leaving that behind and hauling in ambiguous tags like [grid](/questions/tagged/grid) or [styles](/questions/tagged/styles) will show the question to Java programmers, CSS people, iPhone developers and thousands more who know nothing about WPF and may even contribute misinformation in the form of comments or misguided answers.

For the huge tags like [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf), it's actively a good thing to add another tag that starts `wpf-` to narrow it down to something people might actually be interested in and follow / not follow. I would addd the ambiguous (cross-platform, cross-language, cross-framework) tags only if there was nothing more specific available.

In a smaller tag like [windows-store-apps](/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps) perhaps adding generic tags might be helpful. But do you think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637197/disable-default-keyevent-of-a-button-windows-8-metro is helped by having [button](/questions/tagged/button) added to the hugely generic [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)? I don't.

Comment: But isn't the [tag:wpf-controls] doing it a disservice? I don't expect that it adds much more information or draws that much of a different crowd. That's like having a [tag:Lego] [tag:Lego-blocks]. What else are you going to talk about? I see a need for [tag:c#] and [tag:wpf] because you can do wpf in another language, and you can do other things in c#. Otherwise, if you only want controls people to look at your question, then don't add the [tag:wpf] at all, **only use the [tag:wpf-controls] tag. Again, this isn't about not having the tags, but about not tagging a single question with both.**

Comment: choose too narrowly - say only wpf-datagrid-columns - and you miss the attention of someone who cares about of lot of WPF, but doesn't follow all the little tags. Choose too widely and you get answers from people who don't know the subject. Since we get 5 tags, using them for both the wide and narrow - wpf and wpf-datagrid-columns - hurts no-one and attracts the right crowd.

Comment: Yeah, but you add broad and narrow and you still attract the broad crowd, it's not a intersect, it's a union. So you still get the answers from people who don't know the subject.